# Haskell gtk2hs closing aboutDialogs

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

I'm having some trouble with the close buttons of aboutDialogs in gtk2hs. Here is my code

```
 aboutMenuAction <- xmlGetWidget xml castToMenuItem "menuAbout"
 onActivateLeaf aboutMenuAction $ do ad <- aboutDialogNew
                                     aboutDialogSetName ad "..."
                                     aboutDialogSetAuthors ad ["...","..."]
                                     widgetShowAll ad
```

This displays the aboutDialog fine, but the close button doesn't function at all. I wasn't able to find much about this, and have no idea how to get the close button functioning.

Cheers, Josh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
about = do
    ad <- aboutDialogNew
    aboutDialogSetName ad "Horde Test Program"
    aboutDialogSetVersion ad "1.0"
    aboutDialogSetAuthors ad $ ["Thomas M. DuBuisson "
        ++ "<Thomas.DuBuisson@gmail.com>"]
    aboutDialogSetComments ad $ ""
    dialogRun ad
    widgetDestroy ad
```

And to create that `about` dialog I have some buttons:

```
qa <- buttonNewFromStock stockAbout
onClicked qa $ about
-- ...
bb <- hButtonBoxNew
containerAdd bb qa
```

Disclaimer: For this program I took the [carsim](http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs/gtk/demo/carsim/) GTK demo as a starting point, so the code and even variable names probably still match that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, turns out the problem was using widgetShowAll instead of dialogRun which you use. Thanks!